# Rendering the generated Latex of a formula programmatically through javascript One-By-One

Tags: javascript, mathjax

Please forgive me if my question not belongs to be here:

I just got stuck in a problem, I’ve searched through the documentation and the group, but I couldn’t find any precise solution of my Problem.

Actually I’d like to display mathematics equation one-by-one trough JavaScript on my web page. So to achieve this i have a JSON data having n number of mathematics equation, now when i load the page i need to display just one math equation and in this case i got succeed, But when i fired onclick event on JSON data and try to display next math equation then The MathJax library not working for any other math equation except first math equation which is displayed alongside with page load.

I have math equation converted in latex form and i am putting this latex to my web page for MathJax and i already added MathJax library to my Web Page. Need help. Thanks.

I tried following code so far

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "/static/MathJax-2.6-latest/MathJax.js";   // use the location of your MathJax

      var config = 'MathJax.Hub.Config({ config: "MathJax.js" }); ' +
                   'MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';

      if (window.opera) {script.innerHTML = config}
                   else {script.text = config}

      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    })();
</script>
```

form https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.0/dynamic.html and i am also trying to configure https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.0/typeset.html but not succeed.

**Edit**. I have a JSON data

```html
[{"id":292,"equation":"\\(\\frac{1}{{1\\frac{1}{4}}} + \\frac{1}{{6\\frac{2}{3}}} - \\frac{1}{x} + \\frac{1}{{10}} = \\frac{{11}}{{12}},\\) What if the value of X?","eOption1":"\\(\\frac{{15}}{3}\\)","eOption2":"\\(\\frac{{20}}{{15}}\\)","eOption3":"\\(\\frac{{15}}{2}\\)","eOption4":"\\(\\frac{{12}}{{12}}\\)","Solution":"\\(\\frac{1}{{1\\frac{1}{4}}} + \\frac{1}{{6\\frac{2}{3}}} - \\frac{1}{x} + \\frac{1}{{10}} = \\frac{{11}}{{12}}\\)\r\\(\\frac{1}{{\\frac{5}{4}}} + \\frac{1}{{\\frac{{20}}{3}}} - \\frac{1}{x} + \\frac{1}{{10}} = \\frac{{11}}{{12}}\\)\r\\(\\frac{4}{5} + \\frac{3}{{20}} - \\frac{1}{x} + \\frac{1}{{10}} = \\frac{{11}}{{12}}\\)\r\\( \\Rightarrow \\frac{1}{x} = \\frac{4}{5} + \\frac{3}{{20}} + \\frac{1}{{10}} - \\frac{{11}}{{12}} = \\frac{{48 + 9 + 6 - 55}}{{60}}\\)\r\\( = \\frac{{63 - 55}}{{60}} = \\frac{8}{{60}} = \\frac{2}{{15}}\\)\r\\(\\frac{1}{x} = \\frac{2}{{15}} \\Rightarrow x = \\frac{{15}}{2}\\)"},

{"id":293,"equation":"\\(7.\\overline 7 \\) Find the value of?"","eOption1":"\\(\\frac{{80}}{9}\\)","eOption2":"\\(\\frac{{70}}{9}\\)","eOption3":"\\(\\frac{{60}}{9}\\)","eOption4":"\\(\\frac{{50}}{9}\\)","eOption5":"","eOption6":"","eOption7":"","eOption8":"","answer":"b","Solution":"\\(7.\\overline 7  = 7 + 0.\\overline 7  = 7 + \\frac{7}{9} = \\frac{{70}}{9}\\)","Solution":"\\(7.\\overline 7  = 7 + 0.\\overline 7  = 7 + \\frac{7}{9} = \\frac{{70}}{9}\\)"}...}]
```

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var index = 0;
     var equationList = ${Question};
     $(document).ready(function() {
     qList = question;
     render();
     console.log('equationList--'+JSON.stringify(qList ));
});


and now my render function looks like following where i am displaying one equation 

function render() {
  //index=0;
  var list = qList[index];        

    $('#question').html(list.equation);

    $('#op1').html(list.eOption1);
    $('#op2').html(list.eOption2);
    $('#op3').html(list.eOption3);
    $('#op4').html(list.eOption4);
};

//onClick function()//

function displayNextEquestion() {
  index++;
  //index=1;
  render(); 
}
</script>
```

In the Above code when render is called first time alongside page load it display first question properly but when function "displayNextEquestion()" called it is unable to display second question properly.

And in my web Page having

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "/static/MathJax-2.6-latest/MathJax.js";   // use the location of your MathJax

      var config = 'MathJax.Hub.Config({ config: "MathJax.js" }); ' +
                   'MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();';

      if (window.opera) {script.innerHTML = config}
                   else {script.text = config}

      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    })();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.0-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

and more thing i am using latest chrome web browser, hoping this is not raising any issue. Thanks

Comment: You should probably add a code sample that shows what you've tried so far.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger i am added some sample have a look thank.

Comment: This is not helping much, I'm afraid. You should show what you are doing beyond MathJax. Also, you should update to a recent version of MathJax and check its documentation -- v1.0 is over 7 years old, v2.0 is almost 5 years old.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger i am updated to the latest version nothing changed. and have a Look To the Edited section for complete scenario.

Comment: Please take more time searching SO, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mathjax+jquery immediately gives you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513851/mathjax-in-jquery.  Alternatively, read the documentation you link to, e.g., http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html.